# Using custom instance when deriving an instance via GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving

Tags: haskell, ghc, typeclass, deriving, derivingvia

Suppose that we have a typeclass `class (A a, B a) => C a where`. Using `newtype` will allow us to clone a data type and then automatically derive the instances via the `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` language
extension (See [how to write a derivable class?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14755613) and [Handling multiple types with the same internal representation and minimal boilerplate?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3731416)).

**QUESTION** : Is it possible to get ghc to automatically derive `A` and `C`, but to use our own specified implementation of `B` in deriving `C`?

For example the following code (where `A` = `Planet`, `B` = `Lives`, `C` = `Description`) does not work as expected :

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
module Main (main) where

data Cat = Cat String
newtype Dolphin = Dolphin Cat deriving (Planet)

------------------------------------------------

class Planet a where
  planet :: a -> String

class Lives a where
  lives :: a -> String

class (Planet a, Lives a) => Description a where
  description :: a -> String

------------------------------------------------

instance Planet Cat where
  planet _ = "lives on planet earth,"

instance Lives Cat where
  lives _ = "lives on land"

instance Description Cat where
  description a = (planet a) ++ (lives a)

------------------------------------------------

instance Lives Dolphin where
  lives _ = "lives in the sea"

--want the following derivation to use the instance of 
--"Lives" for "Dolphin" above
deriving instance Description Dolphin

------------------------------------------------

main = do
  print $ description (Cat "test")
  -- > "lives on planet earth,lives on land"
  -- OK
  print $ description (Dolphin (Cat "test"))
  -- > "lives on planet earth,lives on land"
  -- NOT OK. Want "lives on planet earth,lives in the sea"
```

What I was expecting/wanted was for the `Dolphin` instance of `Lives` to be invoked in the derivation of `Description`.

Obviously the following program works, but it requires one to explicitly instantiate `Description` for `Dolphin` :

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
module Main (main) where

data Cat = Cat String
newtype Dolphin = Dolphin Cat deriving (Planet)

------------------------------------------------

class Planet a where
  planet :: a -> String

class Lives a where
  lives :: a -> String

class (Planet a, Lives a) => Description a where
  description :: a -> String

------------------------------------------------

instance Planet Cat where
  planet _ = "lives on planet earth,"

instance Lives Cat where
  lives _ = "lives on land"

instance Description Cat where
  description a = (planet a) ++ (lives a)

------------------------------------------------

instance Lives Dolphin where
  lives _ = "lives in the sea"

instance Description Dolphin where
  description a = (planet a) ++ (lives a)

------------------------------------------------

main = do
  print $ description (Cat "test")
  -- > "lives on planet earth,lives on land"
  --[OK]
  print $ description (Dolphin (Cat "test"))
  -- > "lives on planet earth,lives in the sea"
  --[OK]
```

p.s. What is puzzling is that if (in the first program) I do not declare :

```
instance Lives Dolphin where
  lives _ = "lives in the sea"
```

Then ghc complains :

```
Main.hs:36:1:
    No instance for (Lives Dolphin)
      arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration
    In the instance declaration for ‘Description Dolphin’
```

Seems strange that ghc would complain about the absence of `instance Lives Dolphin where` if it is **not** using it in the (automatic) derivation of `Description` for `Dolphin`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
newtype ProcessID = PID Int deriving Eq
```

What this does is write an instances that looks like

```
instance Eq PID where
  (PID x) == (PID y)    =    x == y
```

In other words, when you call `==` on a `PID`, it unwraps it into an ordinary `Int`, and then executes `==` on that.

I imagine the `deriving instance Description Dolphin` is doing exactly the same; unwrapping a `Dolphine` into a `Cat`, and then calling the `description` method on that. Which isn't what you want at all!

Question: If the definition of `description` is always the same, why does it need to be a class at all? Why can't you just define a regular function that does this?

(Or is this a simplification of some more complicated problem you want to solve?)

Comment: `unwrapping a Dolphine into a Cat, and then calling the description method on that` : If this is happening, then ghc will not be using `instance Lives Dolphin where` (but will instead use `instance Lives Cat where`). So then why does ghc complain if this `instance Lives Dolphin where` is absent from the first program?

Comment: `Question: If the definition of description is always the same, why does it need to be a class at all? Why can't you just define a regular function that does this?` - this is just a simplification of a situation I had in mind. Effectively I imagined having a complex type-class heirarchy and that I want to modify the behaviour (for a given type) of one instance in the middle of that type class heirarchy without having to declare a new type and redeclare all the instances, with only one instance modified. Ideally I would only declare the modified instance.

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible with [`DerivingVia`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/deriving_via.html?highlight=derivingvia#extension-DerivingVia). First you define a newtype wrapper

```hs
newtype Describe a = Describe a
 deriving
 newtype (Planet, Lives)

instance (Planet a, Lives a) => Description (Describe a) where
  description :: Describe a -> String
  description a = planet a ++ lives a
```

Then you can derive an instance of `Dolphin` via `Describe Dolphin`

```
{-# Language DerivingVia #-}

newtype Dolphin = Dolphin Cat
 deriving
 newtype Planet

 deriving Description
 via Describe Dolphin
```

Now:

```
>> main
"lives on planet earth,lives on land"
"lives on planet earth,lives in the sea"
```