# "Inherited" type (via GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving) not using derived instance

Tags: haskell, ghc, typeclass

(Related to [Using custom instance when deriving an instance via GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27571698/using-custom-instance-when-deriving-an-instance-via-generalizednewtypederiving)). Suppose that I have :

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
module Main (main) where

data Cat = Cat String deriving (Show)
newtype Dolphin = Dolphin Cat deriving (Info,Show)

class Info a where
  info :: a -> (a,String)

instance Info Cat where
  info a = (a,show a)

main = do
  print $ info (Cat "mammal")
  --OK
  --OUTPUT 1 : (Cat "mammal","Cat \"mammal\"")

  print $ info (Dolphin $ Cat "mammal")
  --NOT OK
  --OUTPUT 2 : (Dolphin (Cat "mammal"),"Cat \"mammal\"")

  print $ show (Dolphin $ Cat "mammal")
  --OUTPUT 3 : "Dolphin (Cat \"mammal\")"
```

In output 2, we know that `info` is operating on an argument of type `Dolphin` (see the first element of the tuple), and yet it prints out `"Cat \"mammal\""` for the second element of the tuple. Yet we know that `show` executed on an argument of type `Dolphin` should print out `"Dolphin (Cat \"mammal\")"` (see output 3). So why does ghci (in output 2) print out `"(Dolphin (Cat "mammal"),"Cat \"mammal\"")"` when I think it should print out `"(Dolphin (Cat "mammal"),"Dolphin (Cat \"mammal\")")"`?

Comment: Perhaps you were expecting the derived instance to copy the source code from the other instance, to produce `instance Info Dolphin where info a = (a, show a)`. While the types happen to work out in this case, they might not in general: imagine writing `showCat :: Cat -> String; showCat = show; instance Info Cat where info a = (a, showCat a)`. Now when you copy this source code to the new instance `instance Info Dolphin where info a = (a, showCat a)` you are trying to call `showCat` on a `Dolphin`! So instead newtype deriving must unwrap argument values and rewrap result values.

Comment: @DanielWagner : that's a very good explanation. Makes complete sense now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only instance for `Info` with any code is the one for `Cat`, so the only possible value of the second element of the tuple is the result of `show (a :: Cat)` which is invariably `"Cat \"...\""`. The `Info` instance for `Dolphin` came from `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`; it does *exactly* what the `Info` instance for `Cat` did.

The `Show` instance for `Dolphin` did not come from `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`, it came from the ordinary mechanism for `deriving (Show)`. It shows `Dolphin` as you expect. In the second example `show (a :: Dolphin)` is being used by the `Show` instance for `(Show a, Show b) => Show (a, b)` used by  `print` to display a tuple of type `(Dolphin, String)`.

The confusing bit here is that the `Info` instance for `Cat` is returning a tuple of type `(Cat, String)`. The only thing `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` is doing is replacing `Cat` with `Dolphin` everywhere the type variable appeared in the `Info` instance. This gives an `info :: Dolphin -> (Dolphin, String)` that does exactly what `info :: Cat -> (Cat, String)` did.